# What is the probability of a defective paint job?

Tags: probability, statistics

After the initial production run of a new style of a steel desk, a quality control technician found that 40% of the desks had an alignment problem and 10% had both a defective paint job and an alignment problem. If a desk is randomly selected from this run and it has an alignment problem, what is the probability that it also has a defective paint job? (Let "A" be the event "having an alignment problem" and D be the event "having a defective paint job")

Comment: Any thoughts?  Suggestion:  try concrete numbers.  Suppose there are exactly $100$ desks in total. Work it out in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the different issues as an event that has a certain probability. Let $A$ be the event that there is an alignment issue, and $B$ be the event that there is a defective paint job.

The question provides you with two facts:

(1) The probability that there is an alignment issue is 40%.

> $P(A)=0.4$

(2) The probability that there is both an alignment issue, and a defective paint job is 10%

> $P(A\cap B)=0.1$

The question is asking a fundamental property of the probability of the event $B$ happening given that $A$ has occurred. Since $A$ has occurred, you no longer need to consider the case in which there is no alignment issue. This narrows the scope of possibilities.

Comment: You are missing an important point- are we to assume that "alignment problem" and "defective paint job" are **independent**  If so then because 10% of all desks have a defective paint job, 10% of the badly aligned ones do also.   That is 10% of 40%= 4% are badly aligned **and** have a defective paint job.

Comment: @user247327 No, we are *not* to assume independence . We are *told* that $10\%$ of *all* desks are *both* badly aligned *and* have a defective paint job.

Comment: @user247327 You are incorrect. If what you're suggesting is true, the exercise should have been worded "40% of all desks have alignment issues, and 10% of all desks have paint job issues. What is the probability that any given desk has both an alignment issue and a defective paint job?" Rather, the exercise explicitly provides the probability of both events happening, and assumes that one of them indeed has happened.

This is a problem of **conditional probability** rather than probability of intersecting events.

Plus, if these events were independent the probability of both at once is 0.